# Which collection should be preferred to handle, store and iterate over a large number of window popups using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, list, selenium, collections, set

I am aware of the fact that we can handle window popups using driver.getWindowHandles() and then store it in a Set and then iterate over it. But what if there are more than 100 window popups?

Consider a scenario where user navigates to a webpage with a link on it. It clicks on this link a new window popup appears and then user click on link on that popup and again another window popup appears and so on..upto 100 or more popups..

Which collection should be preferred in such case? or what approach should be applied in such a case?

Comment: What's wrong with `Set`?

Comment: @Kushal This question was asked to me in an interview.. The interviewer said if the number of window popups increased, eventually set may give some memory error..so which approach should be used in such case?

Comment: Why not to get href and open in the same window?

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate with `winHandles.size();`:

```
for(int i = 0; i<= winHandles.size(); i++) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### getWindowHandles()

As per the documentation [**`getWindowHandles()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getWindowHandles--) is defined as:

```
java.util.Set<java.lang.String> getWindowHandles()

Return a set of window handles which can be used to iterate over all open windows of this WebDriver instance by passing them to switchTo().WebDriver.Options.window()

Returns:
    A set of window handles which can be used to iterate over all open windows.
```

So even dealing with 100 or more popups also you are safe.

A generic example:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.Set;

  import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class WINDOW_HANDLE_ITERATE_Set_demo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");
          String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
          System.out.println("Page Title is: "+driver.getTitle());
          ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://facebook.com/');");
          new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
          Set<String> allWindows_1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
          for(String hand1:allWindows_1)
          if(!parent_window.equals(hand1))
          {
              driver.switchTo().window(hand1);
              new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Face"));
              System.out.println("Page Title is: "+driver.getTitle());
              driver.close();
          }
          driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);
          System.out.println("Page Title is: "+driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Page Title is : Google
  Page Title is : Facebook – log in or sign up
  Page Title is : Google
  ```

---

### Alternative

However to navigate through 100 or more popups you can also cast the **`Set<String>`** object into a **`ArrayList<String>`** object as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Set;

  import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class WINDOW_HANDLE_ITERATE_ArrayList_demo
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");
          System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
          String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
          ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://facebook.com/');");
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
          Set<String> allWindows_1 = driver.getWindowHandles(); // this is the casting step
          ArrayList<String> tabs = new  ArrayList<>(allWindows_1);
          driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Facebook"));
          System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
          driver.close();
          driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);
          System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Page Title is : Google
  Page Title is : Facebook – log in or sign up
  Page Title is : Google
  ```

---

### trivia (List vs Set)

*List* and *Set* are the two among several **Collection** classes in Java. Both of them are used to store objects and provides convenient APIs to `insert`, `remove` and `retrieve elements` to support *Iteration* over **Collection**.

- *List* in Java allows duplicates while *Set* doesn't allow any duplicate. If you `insert` duplicate in *Set* it will replace the older value. Any implementation of *Set* in Java will only contains unique elements.
- *List* is an **Ordered Collection** while *Set* is an **unordered Collection**. *List* maintains insertion order of elements, means any element which is inserted before will go on lower index than any element which is inserted after. *Set* in Java doesn't  maintain any order. Though *Set* provide another alternative called *SortedSet* which can store Set elements in specific **Sorting order** defined by comparable and comparator methods of Objects stored in *Set*.
- Popular implementation of *List* interface in Java includes **ArrayList**, **Vector** and **LinkedList**. While popular implementation of *Set* interface includes **HashSet**, **TreeSet** and **LinkedHashSet**.

---

### tl; dr

Here you can find a reference about [Difference between List and Set in Java Collection](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/04/difference-between-list-and-set-in-java.html)